# LIBSVM how to prepare training dataset with images for logo detection?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

**TASK:**
I have more them 100 thousands images taken from videos (video frames) and I need to classify which images have logos from my list.

**THE PROBLEM:**
I created a library of logo images. For the classification task I'm going to use LIBSVM. I need to transform images to the format of an SVM dataset. I've read through materials on the LIBSVM website, FAQ & "A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classication". **But I still can't find answer how to prepare data/images for LIBSVM training.** I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to vectorize your data, using a feature set of your choosing which can be computed based on images. I will not elaborate on all the details here, as it would take up *way* too much space and be off-topic for SO.

In short, the best way to vectorize depends largely on the shapes you want to detect (e.g. the logos). The Hough transform is used almost all the time, amongst others, so you may want to look into that.

Secondly, object detection is generally performed by running a set of classifiers on many pans/zooms/rotations for each single image. In this context you want to be using classifiers with very low run-time complexity. The linear kernel and intersection kernels are commonly used. Intersection kernels are not provided by LIBSVM, but you can compute them for yourself. For complexity reasons, it is probably more interesting to use LIBLINEAR, which explicitly constructs the separating hyperplane and thus predicts at *much* lower complexity.

Comment: Marc, could you clarify please what kind of Hough transformation do you mean? Is it GHT?

Comment: I would also interesting to understand, how the training data/testing data format looking and how to make it as well. Does "Hough transformation" will do the job for us to make the libsvm data format? And how?

Comment: @RomanPodlinov: here is a reference regarding the use of the Hough transform: *S. Maji and J. Malik. Object detection using a max-margin hough transform. In Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR), 2009*. OSIFY: the Hough transform is a mathematical transformation, it does not change the data format.